# Finding McAfee Version with PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I would like to find the McAfee products installed on system. I am trying to run this PowerShell code however its not working:

```
Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* 
    |  Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion, Publisher, InstallDate 
    | Where-Object {$_.DisplayName -contains "McAfee"}
```

Following command displays all list of installed software however filtering is not working:

```
Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* 
   |  Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion, Publisher, InstallDate
```

Please help where I am missing?

Thanks & regards,
Kedar S Tamboli

Answer (score 0, accepted):

-like might be the operator you are looking for.
Try

```
Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* |  Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion, Publisher, InstallDate | Where-Object {$_.DisplayName -like "McAfee*"}
```

This help explains the operators.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847759.aspx

-Contains
      Description: Containment operator. Tells whether a collection of reference
      values includes a single test value. Always returns a Boolean value. Returns TRUE
      only when the test value exactly matches at least one of the reference values.

-Like
      Description: Match using the wildcard character (*).
      Example:

```
      PS C:\> "Windows PowerShell" -like "*shell"
      True

      PS C:\> "Windows PowerShell", "Server" -like "*shell"
      Windows PowerShell
```

Comment: problem is that some installations don't have this information in this registry key, but under SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall instead so I suggest testing both and use the one where some value is found

Answer (score 0):

To get the content version of McAfee on your current working server you can use the following code:

```
$server = hostname

Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\McAfee\AVSolution\DS\DS* | select @{n='Server';e={$server}},dwContentMajorVersion,szContentCreationDate
```

So I tried to invoke function on another server connected in the network.

The below code will help you to get the work done:

```
$server= "Server_Name"



Invoke-Command -cn $server -ScriptBlock {Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\McAfee\AVSolution\DS\DS* | select @{n='Server';e={$server}},dwContentMajorVersion,szContentCreationDate}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
Clear-Host

$MAVersion = "5.6.1.308"

$CompName = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input computer name or ip'

write-host $CompName

$MARemote = (Get-Item \\\$CompName\c$\'Program Files'\McAfee\Agent\cmdagent.exe).VersionInfo.FileVersion

if ($MARemote -ne $MAVersion) {

write-host 'MA Remote ='$MARemote

write-host "Outdated MA" -ForegroundColor Red

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take a moment to read through the [editing help](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the [help]. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than other sites.

Comment: I take it this is your own script for some other purpose since it has elements that weren't part of the question (prompting for and querying a remote machine, comparing with some fixed version number).  Anyways, this assumes that the file version of `cmdagent.exe` reflects the overall installer package version.  Is that necessarily the case?  It seems like the registry would be a more reliable source of that information, as in the question and accepted answer.